# Vuex - Normalizr doesn't work as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex, normalizr

I am creating a simple chat app. I have three entities: rooms, messages and users.
I have a fake API that returns a response like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'room1',
  avatar: 'some img url',
  messages: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'some text',
        user: {
          id: 1,
          username: 'Peter Peterson',
          avatar: 'some img url'
      }
  ]
 }]
```

And my action looks like this:

```
getAllRooms({ commit }) {
  commit(GET_ALL_ROOMS_REQUEST);
  return FakeApi.getAllRooms()
    .then(
      rooms => {
        const { entities } = normalize(rooms, room);
        console.log(entities);
        commit(GET_ALL_ROOMS_SUCCESS, {
          rooms: entities.rooms, byId: rooms.map(room => room.id)
        });
        commit(GET_ALL_MESSAGES_SUCCESS, { messages: entities.messages });
        commit(GET_ALL_USERS_SUCCESS, { users: entities.users });
      },
      err => commit(GET_ALL_ROOMS_ERROR)
    )
}
```

And my mutations look like this:

```
[GET_ALL_ROOMS_REQUEST](state) {
  state.loading = true;
},
[GET_ALL_ROOMS_SUCCESS](state, payload) {
  state.rooms = payload.rooms;
  state.byId = payload.byId;
  state.loading = false;
},
[GET_ALL_ROOMS_ERROR]() {
  state.error = true;
  state.loading = false;
}
```

And my component calls the action like this:

```
{
  mounted() {
    this.getAllRooms();
  }
}
```

These are my schema definitions:

```
const user = new schema.Entity('users');

const message = new schema.Entity('messages', {
  user: user
});

const room = new schema.Entity('rooms', {
  messages: [message]
})
```

when i check the response in then method after FakeApi.getAllRooms() every object is wrapped in some weird Observer, and I pass it like that to normalize and normalize returns some weird response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't with vuejs, it was with the way I made the normalizr schemas. Because my response is an array at the root I should have had a new `rooms` array schema, like so:

```
const user = new schema.Entity('users');

const message = new schema.Entity('messages', {
  user: user
});

const room = new schema.Entity('rooms', {
  messages: [message]
});

const roomsSchema = [room];
```

And then use it like this: `normalize(rooms, roomsSchema)`